# Let $U: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ be a harmonic function such that $U(z)\ge 0 \ \forall z\in \mathbb C$ ; then $U$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $U: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ be a harmonic function such that $U(z)\ge 0 \ \forall z\in \mathbb C$ ; then $U$ is constant.

[Let $u:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function such that $0\leq f(z)$ for all $ z \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $u$ is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538221/let-u-mathbbc-rightarrow-mathbbr-be-a-harmonic-function-such-that-0-leq)

I don't know about simply connected domain. Can we do it without using that?

Edit: The more elementary the proof, the better. I'm working my way through a complex analysis workbook, and by this exercise, the substantial things covered are Lioville's theorem, Maximum modulus theorem.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @TrevorGunn, I don't know the theory of simply connected domain. So can we do it without using it?

Comment: This is Theorem 3.1 in Harmonic Function Theory by Axler, Bourdon, and Ramey. See http://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Another, similar, way to go:

Again, since $U: \Bbb C \to \Bbb R$ is defined everywhere, it has a global harmonic conjugate $V: \Bbb C \to \Bbb R$ and then

$F(z) = U(z) + iV(z) \tag 1$

is entire.  Thus

$e^{F(z)} = e^{U(z) + iV(z)}, \tag 2$

is also entire, as is

$e^{-F(z)} = e^{-U(z) - iV(z)}; \tag 3$

we have

$\vert e^{-F(z)} \vert = \vert e^{-U(z) - iV(z)} \vert = \vert e^{-U(z)}e^{-iV(z)} \vert = \vert e^{-U(z)} \vert \vert e^{-iV(z)} \vert; \tag 4$

now

$\vert  e^{-iV(z)} \vert = 1, \tag 5$

since $V(z)$ is real, thus

$\vert e^{-F(z)} \vert = \vert  e^{-U(z)} \vert \le 1, \tag 6$

since $U(z) \ge 0$ implies $-U(z) \le 0$.  Thus $e^{-F(z)}$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).  Thus $-F(z)$, and hence $F(z)$, must also be constant.  Thus $U(z)$ is constant as well.

Comment: Can we solve this problem without using that $U$ has global harmonic conjugate?

Comment: @User:  I guess you could look at Guy Fsone's answer for that!

Comment: simple and beautiful answer.

Answer (score 3):

### MORE GENERAL AND SIMPLE ANSWER

> Liouville Type (Theorem's)
>   Suppose $u:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ be a nonegaitve harmonic function 
>   Then, $u$ is constant.

**Proof**
$u\ge 0$ then $\inf_{\mathbb R^d} u<\infty$. Hence we set 
$$v= u-\inf_{\mathbb R^d} u$$
and

\begin{split} \begin{cases}\Delta v=0\\
v\ge 0\\
\inf_{\mathbb R^d} v =0\end{cases}\end{split}

Let $\varepsilon>0,$ and $y\in\mathbb R^d$  then there exists $x_\varepsilon$ such that,

$$ v(x_\varepsilon)\le \inf_{\mathbb R^d} v+\varepsilon$$

Let $R>\max(|x_\varepsilon|,|y|)+1$ therefore, $x_\varepsilon,y\in B_R(0)$ and

$$ B_R(y)\subset B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon) $$

**By Mean value property (The mean value is true in any dimension for harmonics functions)**,

\begin{split} v(y) &=& \frac{1}{|B_R(y)|}\int_{B_R(y)} v(z) dz\\ &=& \frac{3^d}{|B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon)|}\int_{B_R(y)} v(z) dz \\&\le&\frac{3^d}{|B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon)|}\int_{B_{3R}(x_\varepsilon)} v(z) dz \\&= & 3^d v(x_\varepsilon) \end{split}
This leads to,

$$  v(y)\le 3^d v(x_\varepsilon)\le 3^d(\inf_{\mathbb R^d} v+\varepsilon)~~\forall y\in  \mathbb R^d$$

That is 
$$  \sup_{\mathbb R^d} v < 
  3^d \varepsilon $$

Since $\inf_{\mathbb R^d} v=0$ ~~ but $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrarily chosen, letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ we get

$$ 0\le \sup_{\mathbb R^d} v  \le 0$$

i.e $v = 0$ or $u= \inf_{\mathbb R^d} u $

Comment: In your proof you are assuming that $v$ is bounded. I think this can be avoided if you let $y$ be any point in $\mathbf{R}^d$ and then, by the same argument, $v(y) \le 3^d \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks I have edidted

Answer (score 2):

> **EDIT:  This answer was in response to the original OP that asked "Can anybody please explain this solution? I do not understand this solution."  The OP was asking for explanation of the proof provided by Daniel Fischer [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538221/let-u-mathbbc-rightarrow-mathbbr-be-a-harmonic-function-such-that-0-leq).**

---

The proof given [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538221/let-u-mathbbc-rightarrow-mathbbr-be-a-harmonic-function-such-that-0-leq) relies on the fact that a harmonic function on a simply connected domain is the real part of a holomorphic function on that simply connected domain ([For a proof, SEE HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108116/every-harmonic-function-is-the-real-part-of-a-holomorphic-function)).  Hence, we have $u(z)=\text{Re}(f(z))$, for an enire function $f$.

---

Next, since we assume that $u(z)=\text{Re}(f(z))>0$ then $f(z)+1=\left(u(z)+1\right)+i\,\text{Im}(f(z))$ can never be zero.  Hence, the function $g$ given by

$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}$$

is entire.

---

Finally, since

$$\left|\frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{(u(z)-1)^2+\left(\text{Im}(f(z))\right)^2}{(u(z)+1)^2+\left(\text{Im}(f(z))\right)^2}}<1$$

is bounded, then Liouville's Theorem guarantees that $g$ is a constant.  In turn, this implies that $f$ is a constant, which implies that $u$ is a constant.

And we are done!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I have not read Simply connected domain yet so I was trying to solve it without using that.

Comment: Without that assumption, a harmonic function need not be the real part of a holomorphic function.  As an example, $f(z)=\log(|z|)$ is harmonic on the puncture plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, but it is not the real part of a holomorphic function on the punctured plane since $\log(z)$ is multivalued.  Luckily for you, the entire plane is simply connected.  Thus, the proof is legitimate.

Comment: @Yeah, So can we do this question in some other way?

Comment: @user I'm sure there are other ways.  But you asked for asked for an explanation of the proof you referenced. Have I addressed that request?

Comment: No doubt, you have addressed that very well. I was looking for a way without using that.

Comment: Apologies for that.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Much appreciative.

Comment: It's easier to look at $e^{-f},$ which is entire and bounded.

Comment: @zhw. You're right, but the original question requested explanation of the proof referenced in the OP.  Checking the edits, the OP read "Can anybody please explain this solution? I do not understand this solution."